# Calling JasperReports from Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print a report created with Jasper Reports from under Netbeans 8.2, the first report it worked fine for couple of days then it sopped working and I get an error message

**"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester".**

all Jasperreports Jar files do exist in my project under the Directory "Libraries". 
here is the code I use to call Jasper report from my aapplication.

```
 try {
        DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();
        conn = DBModule.ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();

        //Get a stream to read the file
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);

        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, conn);

        JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
        jf.validate();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        jf.setLocation(300,100);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        CustomControls.CustomTools.CustomMsgBox(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Any suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

You not only need "all Jasperreports Jar files" but also some 3rd party libraries. Please have a look at [community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements) about the library requirements. Unless you are not using maven or something similar, i guess you need to copy those to your classpath.